# Airline changes plane, boarding is done by calling names, my name not called, Service insists that I was late

Tags: passenger-rights, airbaltic

Today my gf wanted to flight home (Berlin Tegel -> Minsk). She had booked a flight long ago with airbaltic and checked in 1h before depature.
When boarding should habe started, there was a plane change all of a sudden.
People panicked and where rushing the counters to know what was going on.

In the end, the boarding was done by calling the names on the fligth list one by one. At this point my gf asked one of the service workers there to help her out. She just replied that she needs to wait. So thats what she did.

After all names were called, 5 people were still there. The same service worker insisted that she called all names and therefore these 5 people were obviously late. This obviously was not true.

However, my gf and the other group of 4 called the airline hotline (no counter for airbaltic in Berlin Tegel). To my gf they responded that they will call back. While on phone, the group of 4 left (no traces, so no witnesses that she was indeed at the gate). At some point the hotline called back. Not unsurprisingly they only found, that the Service Workers at the gate had marked them as late and so there is nothig that they can do (ofc they cant -.-)

My gf is crushed. What can we do?
The ticket was scanned at the security control but I am afraid thats the only proove we have that she was there in time.

// UPDATE: My gf was lucky and found the group of 4 and will exchange numbers. That at least gives me a bit of hope

Comment: Sounds to me like the airline used a smaller plane and had to find some way to sneakily bump five people...

Comment: That were my thoughts, too. But how does one proove that?

Comment: @Fuzzyma Can we find out the plane type a) planned and b) used? If the problem is current, the latter may (still) be visible from flightradar24.com ...

Comment: Looks like [AirBaltic is well known for scams like this](https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.airbaltic.com). Maybe start by asking advice from the [German authorities](https://www.lba.de) at +49 531 2355-115 (only Monday-Thursday 10am-1pm).  Good that you exchanged numbers with the others---if you have 4 other victims of the same scam at the same time, the authorities might be particularly interested.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Unfortunately I only have the flight number which is BT212. I dont know which plane types were used.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I just searched the flightnumber on flightradar and it seems to be a DH8D

Comment: Replacing a plane with 145 seats with another one that only has 76 surely resulted in people being bumped from the flight. They owe your gf assistance (rebook her on the next available flight to her final destination) and compensation. You could tell your gf to go to the police and file a claim for fraud (not for being denied boarding, that happens, but for alleging she wasn't there on time when she was), and ask them to request footage from the video cameras near the gate at the airport during the boarding procedure, as well as logs of boarding pass scans. Then tell the airline what you did.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen It was apparently a CS300 replaced by a Q400 about half the size.

Comment: @Fuzzyma https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/bt212 That's to Riga, not Minsk - that's why I found nothing :) Apparently, they usually use an **Airbus A220-300**, but today had had a **Bombardier Dash 8 Q400**

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes sorry. She would have changed flights there. I missed that one!

Comment: Are you asking how she can get her money back?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.